# Merging arrays, grouping and sorting the values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays in which items from 3 groups are mixed up. The crucial keys of the arrays are: **group_id** and **item_order**:

```
$one = array(
            array('group_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Luke', 'item_order' => 0),
            array('group_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Vader', 'item_order' => 1),
            array('group_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Han', 'item_order' => 1)
        );

$two = array(
            array('group_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Jabba', 'item_order' => 1),
            array('group_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Palpatine', 'item_order' => 0),
            array('group_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Bib Fortuna', 'item_order' => 0)
        );
```

I would like to:

1. merge both arrays, so the result is grouped by **group_id**
2. sort by **group_id** ascending
3. finally, sort each group by **item_order** ascending

The result should look like this:

```
array(
    ['group_1'] => array(
                array('group_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Luke', 'item_order' => 0),
                array('group_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Han', 'item_order' => 1)
            );
    ['group_2'] => array(
                array('group_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Palpatine', 'item_order' => 0),
                array('group_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Vader', 'item_order' => 1)
            );
    ['group_3'] => array(
                array('group_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Bib Fortuna', 'item_order' => 0),
                array('group_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Jabba', 'item_order' => 1)
            );
    );
```

I tried [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) but whatever I do at some point the data gets overwritten (as the array keys are strings) and the result is not whole.

Any ideas how do do this the smart way?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it pretty easily using [Ouzo Goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies) library.

Merge your arrays:

```
$array = array_merge($one, $two);
```

Sort by item_order (this way it gets easier):

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['item_order'] > $b['item_order'] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Group it (Ouzo Goodies comes to play):

```
$result = Arrays::groupBy($array, function($element) {
    return $element['group_id'];
});
```

As you want keys to be in group_number format we need to change them:

```
$result = Arrays::mapKeys($result, function($key) {
    return 'group_' . $key;
});
```

And that should do the trick. If you do not want to add new lib to your stack you can look at the source code and grab those functions to your codebase (MIT license).

Comment: Yeah, that's interesting, but I was looking more for a vanilla-PHP solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether the following is the best solution possible, but it works.

(1) Create temporary arrays:

```
$one_tmp = array();
$two_tmp = array();
```

(2) Wrap each row in a string-type key, based on the row's **group_id**, so the groups can be later merged:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($one); $i++) {
    $group_id = $one[$i]['group_id'];
    $one_tmp['group_'.$group_id][$i] = $one[$i];
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($two); $i++) {
    $group_id = $two[$i]['group_id'];
    $two_tmp['group_'.$group_id][$i] = $two[$i];
}
```

(3) Merge grouped temporary arrays recursively:

```
$merged = array_merge_recursive($drugs_tmp, $subdrugs_tmp);
```

(4) Sort by group keys created in point (2):

```
ksort($merged, SORT_NATURAL);
```

(5) Sort each group by **item_order**:

```
foreach ($merged as $key => $value) {
    usort($merged[$key], 'compare_item_order');
}

function compare_item_order($a, $b) {
    return $a['item_order'] - $b['item_order'];
}
```

And voilà! `$merged` is now exactly what I wanted.